# Classes change screen size in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I built two classes just to check something
if I have a class A which just runs pygame and opens a new window let's say 600X600

and then open class B that runs the same, calls to build a new display 
800X800,  if we create a new instance of A, the screen changes to A's size.

A:

```
import pygame


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.flag = True

    def start(self):
        self.disp = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
        while self.flag:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.flag = False

            pygame.display.update()
```

B:

```
from A import A
import pygame

pygame.init()

displ = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
exited = False
while not exited:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exited = True

    newA = A()
    newA.start()
```

How do I not let A change B's screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.display.set_mode` only sets the resolution and returns a surface, therefore calling it two times will just return a new surface and change the window resolution,

There is no way to have two displays at once in pygame but however you can call an alternate script to open up another process (therefore another display) from the existing one.